# How to exclude specific test classes from running in parallel using TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

If we want to run test classes in parallel, we mention following in `testng.xml` -

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
```

Is there any way where we can mark specific test classes not to run in parallel(provided I've above line in testng.xml file)? Any annotation at class level?

Note: I want to handle this using single testng.xml file.

Comment: You can use include and exclude tag in your xml file

Comment: If you want to exclude them from running at all use the Ignore annotation at class level or even package level. If u want to run them sequentially use singleThreaded=true at the class level Test annotation.